# How to show that the mean is (weakly) consistent

Tags: mean, consistency

How can I show that the mean is weakly consistent? Is weakly consistent the same as consistent?

Comment: Is this self-study or homework?  If so, please add the appropriate tag - we'll guide you to an answer, rather than just providing one outright.

Comment: The answer to the second question is yes.

Comment: I an sorry I do not know how to add the appropriate tag